# How to resample every time some threshold has been passed through summation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this:

```py
 df = pd.DataFrame([
     ['A' ,0],['B', 2 ],['C', 2],['D', 1],
     ['E', 3 ],['F', 2 ],['G', 1],['H', 3],['I', 2 ]
], columns=['l', 'A'])
```

```
    A
  A 0 
  B 2 
  C 2
  D 1
  E 3 
  F 2 
  G 1
  H 3
  I 2
```

How do I resample the data such that I pull the nearest value after I have added up to 5 such that I am left with a data frame that looks like this:

```
     A
   D 1
   F 2
   I 2
```

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want to achieve here. Can you explain why `D` belongs to the result, and `E` for example does not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `cumsum()` function to group by the cumulative sum and then divide by 5 and keep the first occurrence of the integer value of a new dividend. For instance:

```py
df['cumsum'] = (df['A'].cumsum()//5).replace(0,np.nan)
df.groupby('cumsum').first() ## keep first

Out[1]:
        l   A
cumsum      
1.0     D   1
2.0     F   2
3.0     I   2
```